# Python requests HTTPDigestAuth KeyError

Tags: python, python-requests

I have to use Digest auth for an external API integration and my idea is to use Requests library.

If I request the "Login" endpoint without any kind of auth specification, I get a 401 status_code and all the header params, which is a good point.

```py
>>> response = requests.post('http://192.168.100.189/digest/frmUserLogin')
>>> response.status_code
401
>>> response.headers
{
  'Server': 'nginx',
  'Date': 'Fri, 30 Apr 2021 14:52:52 GMT',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'WWW-Authenticate': 'X-Digest realm="95279528asjdlasjdal", domain="::", qop="auth", nonce="ZjU0ODY3MDBmOGZiMmMzOWQyNGQ4ODhlYzI2ZmNkNjE6OTUyNzk1Mjhhc2pkbGFzamRhbDo2MDhjMTljNDpjOTc=", opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41", algorithm="MD5", stale="FALSE"',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Expires': '-1'
}
```

After integrating requests I get a KeyError:

```py
>>> response = requests.post('http://192.168.100.189/digest/frmUserLogin', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin', 'admin1234'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Workspace\HealthCamServer\env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Workspace\HealthCamServer\env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Workspace\HealthCamServer\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Workspace\HealthCamServer\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 662, in send
    r = dispatch_hook('response', hooks, r, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Workspace\HealthCamServer\env\lib\site-packages\requests\hooks.py", line 31, in dispatch_hook
    _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Workspace\HealthCamServer\env\lib\site-packages\requests\auth.py", line 267, in handle_401
    prep.headers['Authorization'] = self.build_digest_header(
  File "C:\Users\Workspace\HealthCamServer\env\lib\site-packages\requests\auth.py", line 132, in build_digest_header
    realm = self._thread_local.chal['realm']
KeyError: 'realm'
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that the server which I'm sending the requests adds **X-Digest** instead to **Digest** in the response headers.

Modifying the requests library HTTPDigestAuth class solved the issue.